# HTML Table: Set width for second column onwards using CSS

Tags: html

Can I set the column width for all but first column using CSS?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

HTML tables don't really have "columns" - rows just have first cells, at least as far as markup is concerned. However, you could do something like with CSS selectors:

Given the following markup:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td><td>bar 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td><td>bar 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td><td>bar 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td><td>bar 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table tr td             { width: 20em; }
table tr td:first-child { width: 10em; }
```

This would set the width of the first "column" to 10em, and all other columns to 20em.

You might want to consider [browser support](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/) for `:first-child` though. The alternative is adding a class to the first `<td>` in every `<tr>` (it appears to be supported by pretty well every major browser other than IE6).

Comment: Since I wanted the width of the first col to be auto, I tried the following based on your idea:
table tr td             { width: 20em; }
table tr td:first-child { width: auto; }

Is that correct? It sometimes is wrapping the contents of the first column now unexpectedly.

Comment: @KalEl, yes. The default value of `width` is `auto`, so that looks good to me, unless it was previously getting `width` from somewhere else. It might be worth removing those two rules, and double checking what value cells in the first column were getting for `width` using Firebug or some other CSS debugging tool.

Comment: "HTML tables don't really have "columns" ... as far as markup is concerned." - This is what `col` and `colgroup` elements are for.

Answer (score 7):

Either of these would work:

```
td:not(:first-child) {
    width: 20%;
}
```

```
td:nth-child(n+2) {
    width: 20%;
}
```

Both examples [work in IE9+](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

### [Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/2348705)

Answer (score 2):

Using  CSS2.1, I'm not aware of any possible selector to do it.

However, CSS3 has a not() selector, so if you give your first column a class, you can use a selector `td:not(.your_class)`

Comment: Interesting idea, haven't seen much of CSS3 - looks like `not()` isn't supported by any of the IE current versions (6, 7 or 8). Could you combine `not()` with `:first-child`? Something like `td:not(:first-child)`? If so, that'd avoid the need for a new class.

Comment: @DominicRodger: `not()` is supported by IE9+ and yes it can be used with `:first-child` (any "simple selector"). http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation